# How To Sum DataGridView Amount Column auto VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How i Sum Datagridview Column auto sum when i adding the digit i have use the below code but not working

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
  Dim sum = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
    Select CDec(row.Cells(1).Value)).Sum
        TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString
        End Sub
```

Comment: *"not working"* is NEVER an adequate explanation.  You need to describe EXACTLY what you expect and EXACTLY what actually happens, along with any other relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
            sum = sum + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        Next
        TextBox5.Text = sum.ToString()
```

Comment: Please dont post code only answer, try to add some context of how this will solve the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
Dim total As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Sum(Function(t) Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells(1).Value))
TextBox1.Text = total.tostring()
```